# Не работает модуль openssl в php

Tags: php, config

> Call to undefined function openssl_encrypt()

Хотя в php.ini `extension=php_openssl.dll` указано без точки с запятой в начале, апач перезапущен, консольная команда `php -m` показывает "openssl" в списке загруженных модулей.

В PHP info раздел openssl отсутствует.
**В чём может быть проблема?**

*PS: PHP скачан с [windows.php.net/download/](http://windows.php.net/download/), версия 5.6.38 (VC11 x86 Thread Safe)*

Comment: Может быть в отсутсвии библиотек в СИСТЕМНОЙ дирректории и в директории апача
"ssleay32.dll" в системную папку или в папку bin апача надо закинуть

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, ок, файл `php_openssl.dll` присутствует в папке /ext каталога с php. Скопировать его в апач? Что Вы имеете ввиду под системной директорией?

Comment: я вроде вам про файл `php_openssl.dll` ни слова не написал, я указал какой именно файл вам нужно скопировать из папки `php` в `apache/bin` или в `system32` и это файл `ssleay32.dll`

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, я свой комментарий оставил после того, как Вы свой отредактировали. Скопировал `ssleay32.dll` и в system32, и в bin апача - пока безрезультатно (

Comment: Ну тогда скопируйте остальные три файла, но если мне память не изменяет то они не за ssl отвечают но связаны с ним `libsasl.dll` `libssh2.dll` `libeay32.dll`, достаточно копировать или в папку апача или в системную, в оба места не обязательно

Comment: Кстати да, еще вариант один, у вас апач с поддержко ssl собран? если нет - то никакие из перечисленных манипуляций не помогут =)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, всё, заработало. Спасибо, что намекнули на системную директорию - я добавил в PATH каталог с PHP ) Копировать `ssleay32.dll` куда-либо нет необходимости

Comment: Если php прописана в PATH - действительно не нужно =) но прописывать php в PATH не всегда вариант =) особенно когда на сервере стоит несколько разных версий php